# Azure ServiceBusQueue - logging errors from uamqp

Tags: python, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using the `azure-servicebus` package to retrieve messages from a ServiceBusQueue - my guess is it installed `uamqp` as a dependency.

- `azure-servicebus==7.6.0`
- `uamqp==1.5.1`

After my script runs, I get a ton (hundreds of lines) of the following error codes after which the process finishes with exit code 0 (=succeeds):

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'
Exception ignored in: 'uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessage.__dealloc__'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'
Exception ignored in: 'uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessage.__dealloc__'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'debug'
...
Original exception was:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It looks like the package `uamqp` wants to log something with the `debug` method, but fails to do so because the logger is not instantiated? How can I fix this? Is this something I can fix or do I need to wait for an update of the package?

My code:

```
    from azure.servicebus import (
        ServiceBusClient,
        AutoLockRenewer,
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage,
    )

    # Create connection
    self.current_connection_string = connection_string
    self.current_queue_name = queue_name
    self.service_bus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
            self.current_connection_string
        )
    self.queue_receiver = self.service_bus_client.get_queue_receiver(
            self.current_queue_name, max_wait_time=max_wait_time
        )

    # get messages
    msgs = self.queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_messages_count)
    self.current_open_messages += msgs
    
    # >>> code processing messages ommitted <<<<
    
    # complete messages with a AutoLockRenewer in case the message lock expired in the meantime + close the queue
    autolock_renewer = AutoLockRenewer()
    for msg in self.current_open_messages:
        autolock_renewer.register(
            self.queue_receiver,
            msg,
            max_lock_renewal_duration=100,
        )
        self.queue_receiver.complete_message(msg)
    self.current_open_messages = []

    self.service_bus_client.close()
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the `azure-servicebus` and `uamqp` versions that you're using?

Comment: I added the versions in the question - I only installed `azure-servicebus` though, I guess it installed `uamqp` as a dependency.

Comment: Yes, `uamqp` is a dependency for `azure-servicebus`. Would you also be able to provide the OS that you're running this on? I ran your sample with `max_wait_time=10`, `max_messages_count=20`, and `current_open_messages=[]` and was not able to reproduce these errors that you're seeing. In the processing code that you omitted, do you use any other classes/functions/etc. from `azure-servicebus`?

Would you be able to turn on logging to give us a clue of exactly where this is happening? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus#logging

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your error, however documentation from @swathipil-msft helped me to silence uamqp messages completely: uamqp_logger=logging.getLogger('uamqp') and uamqp_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR) By the way you are not setting logging_enable to neither True nor False in ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(...)